Kuroda's Identities for Impedance Scaling
I am working on my understanding of RF filters and am in the process of designing a low-pass filter with a 3dB point of 1800 MHz and 10 dB of insertion loss at 2200 MHz. Based on these made-up requirements I am making a 5th order maximally-flat filter. The choice of maximally-flat over equi-ripple or linear phase was arbitrary.
Using table 8.3 from Pozar Microwave Engineering I initially got the weights for the filter components as shown below.

With the weights in hand I used impedance and frequency scaling to simulate the filter in LTspice using lumped components


I was satisfied with the simulation so I moved back to the normalized weights and started applying kuroda's first (a) and second (b) identities (shown in the table below) to convert all the components in my filter to be parallel so they can easily be implemented in microstrip.

There are a total of 3 steps to convert everything to parallel. They are shown below. Note that since the weights are symmetric I only focus on one half of the filter and insert unit elements to the left of the filter.  The 3 steps are shown below as well as the final result




Now at this point I know I need impedance from around 25 ohms to 130 ohms to fabricate my filter. I was hoping to use oshparks 4 layer boards which have a first layer made of 7.87 mil thick FR408HR 2113 prepreg (3.61 dielectric constant). To make 130 ohm traces on this board would require a 1-2 mil wide trace which is not within oshparks tolerances.
This brings me to my question: In both section 8.5 of Pozar's Microwave Engineering and other resources on Kuroda's identities it is stated that there are useful to "Change impractical characteristic impedance into more realizable values" but I am unsure how to use Kurodas identities to change the impedance of a given unit element to something more desirable. Any advice on how I might use Kuroda's identities or any other technique to change my impedance to something more realizable would be great. I am guessing another option would be to change substrates/transmission line topology. For sake of learning I would like to focus on solutions that lower/raise the highest/lowest impedance in my design regardless of substrate or transmission line topology.
One obvious thing I could try is to scale the impedance of my filter and then match it to 50 ohms with a tapered matching circuit or something similar. Example if I choose Z0 = 25 ohms then my smallest/biggest impedance would be 12.5 and 65 ohms respectively which lead to 11 mil to 105 mil respectively both of which could be fabricated. I am not crazy about the matching taper required for this approach.
http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/723/handouts/Kurodas%20Identities%20.pdf
